# How to use get_avatar and force HTTPS?

Tags: wordpress

I have a blog that's all over https. I'm using Gravatar to display a user's profile image like so:

```
<? echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('user_email'), $size = '56'); ?>
```

Problem is that this is http, how can I make this https?

Comment: WordPress will ensure HTTPS **if** SSL is being used. What is the result of `if ( is_ssl() )`? `false` will mean SSL isn't being used on that particular page which will result in HTTP being used

Comment: Strange, I tried outputting <?php is_ssl(); ?> and it's not returning anything. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [get_avatar function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) is located in  [wp-includes/pluggable.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L0).  There is an if statement built in to check if the site is served over an ssl and if it is, to use the link in the code below.  So it should  already check if you are forcing an ssl connection and use the proper link.

```
2075            if ( is_ssl() ) {
2076                    $host = 'https://secure.gravatar.com';
```

Although sometimes there are bugs that cause the gravatar not to show up which I have come by. Are you getting any errors or is your ssl connection showing partially secured?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the accepted solution is if you're caching this data, it may end up caching http (if you serve your blog over both http and https) and later serve it on https, causing warnings, so I'd rather force https.

Here's how to do it right:

`get_avatar( $id, $size, null, false, array('scheme' => 'https') );`

Comment: On which file do we add this?